# Keycloak RC4-With Hmac

Tags: java, single-sign-on, kerberos, keycloak

I am using Keycloak 8.0.1 with java 11(Amazon corretto) on both Windows 2019 server and CentOS 8.1 with the same keycloak configuration using Standalone-HA configuration. Both keycloak servers are behind HA proxy. Under Linux I receive error with SSO - RC4 with HMAC encryption type is not in permitted_enctypes list. How can I avoid this error and why it appears only on my Linux machine ? The keytab was generated with -crypto all. Is there some possibility to force keycloak to use another algorithm or allow RC4 with HMAC encryption ?

Answer (score 1):

Just for others stucked by this error - the solution was to edit  /etc/krb5.conf.d/crypto-policies , I tried to edit krb5.conf instead.